# How to replace aura with babe?

Tags: babe, aura

Subsrate-node-template uses Aura as a default  block authoring algorithem. How can one repalace aura with babe?

Comment: duplicate of https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/368/how-to-change-consensus-engine-from-poa-to-pos, and related to https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/996/how-to-upgrade-consensus-engine-of-a-live-chain-from-poa-to-pos

Answer (score 1):

As Substrate-node-template is based on POA(Proof of Authority) Consensus. In order to replace aura with babe you need to shift the substrate-node-template to POS(proof of stake) consensus.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace aura with babe but easier way is to use the [substrate node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) directly which already implements babe and has NPoS consensus.

If you still want to convert aura to babe than first go through their [definitions](https://docs.substrate.io/learn/consensus/#default-consensus-models), babe is a weight based algorithm and aura is round robin. So to change it first you need to change `node/src/service.rs` file in `node-template` you can have reference from [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/service.rs) and you also need to change the `client` and `grandpa` according to `babe`.

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated the POS in fresh node-template on **polkadot-v1.0.0**

Here you can find the POS(proof-of-stake) node-template with babe: https://github.com/Aideepakchaudhary/POA-to-POS

Thanks!