# Maintained Substrate-NPoS-template?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, npos

Substrate has a `substrate-node-template` with Aura consensus which is well maintained and updated time to time. Do we have a same kind of template for NPoS consensus which is well maintained and updated?

Comment: Please see [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10097/node-template-with-pos-babe-consensus-removal-of-unnecessary-extra-pallets) & [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/368/how-to-change-consensus-engine-from-poa-to-pos) related posts.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are looking for? Aura consensus uses a round-robin scheduling to select which validators should perform some work. In order to be used correctly, it assumes that the validators that will be scheduled have been previously selected from a larger set of validators using, for example, NPoS/DPoS. I'm not sure that you'd like to have a NPoS at the consensus layer where Aura operates.