# Node template with POS Babe consensus: Removal of Unnecessary Extra Pallets

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, babe, pallet-staking, pos

Here is the node template with Babe:
`https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6a946fc36d68b89599d7ca1ab03803d10c78468c/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1583`

The above template is functioning smoothly under POS consensus. However, I think it incorporates several extra pallets. Could anyone please identify the redundant pallets integrated into the template that can be removed without disrupting its functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is the `kitchensink` runtime and is configured with many pallets on purpose (to mimic a chain that is closer to how a real chain would be configured). If you want to use a chain with PoS (`babe`) without all the extra features you could use the `node-template` and change the consensus from PoA (`aura`) to PoS ([have a look at this SE post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/368/how-to-change-consensus-engine-from-poa-to-pos)).

If you want to remove pallets from the `kitchensink-runtime`, I would say the pallets you'd need for a bare metal `PoS node-template` are:

- `System`
- `Babe`

  - `Staking` (required for `babe`)
  - `Session` ("")
- `Grandpa` (for solo chain)
- `Timestamp`
- `Balances` (if you want a native token)
- `TransactionPayment` (if you want users pay fees for transactions)
- `Sudo` (if you want a `Root` user, good for during development)

So remove all the others you can find in the runtime.